# Null web service, using a jax ws client generated with wsimport and a WSDL file

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I followed [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html) guide to create a jax ws client.

Using a private WSDL file I created a set of classes using wsimport, folloing [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/) other guide.

I'm having a problem with this lines:

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/
      helloservice/hello?wsdl")
static HelloService service;
```

Running the test application, service is null. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: can you find out within the generated classes , which one contains @WebServiceClient

Comment: Yes I have found one that says @WebServiceClient(name = "HelloService", targetNamespace = "http://ws.test.com/", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/testClient/testClientWs?wsdl")

Comment: alright how about trying this location in your @WebServiceRef or using @WebServiceRef(the_class_where_you_found_webserviceclient.class)

Comment: The locations of WebServiceClient and WebServiceRef are the same and the error happens. The code I put in the question was taken from oracle page as a reference.

Comment: okk i see. if you are able to access the wsdl then probably the service is availabe but you are missing a configuration